# change of button's id lead to fire of click event

Tags: javascript, jquery

I try to make a click event with jquery.

The result I want is shown below:

> first click - plus one
>
> second click - plus one
>
> third click - plus one & change of button's id and text
>
> fourth click onward - plus one & alert pop-out

However, the alert pop-out at the third click.

my html:

```
<h1 id="number">0</h1>
<button id="next">Add 1</button>
```

my jquery:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
      let num = 0;

      $("#next").click(function () {
        ++num;
        if (num > 2) {
          $("#next").html("Alert");
          $("#next").attr('id', 'alert');
          $("#number").html(num);
        } else {
          $("#number").html(num);
        }

      });
      $(document).on("click", "#alert", function () {
        alert(num);
      });
    });
```

I don't know where I went wrong, in theory this looks fine to me but I am new to jquery and I must have missed something.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On the third click

- call `e.stopPropagation()` to prevent the `#next` click event being propogated to `#alert` element.
- unbind the `#next` click event using `$("#next").unbind("click");` or else `$("#next").click` will be triggered on clicking `#alert`

Also dont forget to handle the alert and increment logic inside `"#alert"` click event.

**Working Fiddle**

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
  let num = 0;
  $("#next").click(function (e) {
    ++num;
    if (num > 2) {
      $("#next").unbind("click");
      $("#next").html("Alert");
      $("#next").attr('id', 'alert');
      $("#number").html(num);
      e.stopPropagation();   
    } else {
      $("#number").html(num);
    }
  });
  $(document).on("click", "#alert", function () {
    ++num;
    alert(num);
    $("#number").html(num);
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<h1 id="number">0</h1>
<button id="next">Add 1</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try following code:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
      let num = 0;
       $(document).on("click", "#next", function () {
        num++;
        if (num > 2) {
          $("#next").html("Alert");
          $("#next").attr('id', 'alert');
          $("#number").html(num);
        } 
        else {
          $("#number").html(num);
        }

      });
      
 $(document).on("click", "#alert", function () {
        num++;
        $("#number").html(num);
         alert(num);
        });
    });
```

Hope it will work.

Comment: You are welcome. If it solved the issue then you can check upper arrow to mark it useful. Thanks